# Pointing apache DocumentRoot to Laravel gives 403 Forbidden error

Tags: laravel, apache, centos

I wanted to host my laravel project on google CentOS 7 server. Following the instructions I have install the laravel project and have changed `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` files changing `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/laravel/public` and `<Directory /var/www/html/laravel`. Now when I open my website `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`. However, when I proceed to `mysite.com/laravel/public` my website loads perfectly, meaning that I'm in `www` folder even if I have changed the `DocumentRoot`. `httpd -S` points to my laravel public folder - `Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html/unionbox.pro/public"`. When I change DocumentRoots back to `/var/www/html` my website just list files and folder in the `www` directory when I open my website. I would appreciate your help! (have been trying to resolve it for 2 days)

Comment: If your DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html/laravel/public` your Directory should be `<Directory /var/www/html/laravel/public` too. Restart Apache after making changes

Comment: @brombeer Changed it, same result. I have CentOS Webpanel installed. Can files of cwp be conflicting with apache or smth?

Comment: @brombeer Actually, I've put ```index.php``` in my ```/var/www/html``` folder and 403 Forbidden disappeared. However I have ```/var/www/html/laravel/public``` set as my Document Root, but apache still considers ```/var/www/html``` as my main directory.